# angular scope.$watch not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive where i bind the tabInfo to tabdata which is an array.

```
angular.module('widgets')
  .directive('tabs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'info',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        controllerAs: 'tabs',
        bindToController: {
            tabInfo: '=tabdata'
        },
        templateUrl: 'Template.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabs) {
            scope.$watch('tabs.tabInfo', function() {
                tabs.populateDataProvider();
            }, true);
        },
        controller: ['$filter', '$state', function($filter, $state) {
        }]
    };
});
```

I need to watch on the "tabInfo" for any change and populate some data. However , my watch is not called at all. Is there something wrong here , in the way that I am refering to tabs.tabInfo?

Comment: you need `var tabs = this` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

A better solution to this would be to have an `ng-if` along with the directive so as to make sure that the directive is rendered only when there is data to populate . This avoids the need of having a watcher inside the directive .

So you could use ,

```
<tabs ng-if="$ctrl.tableData.length" tab-info="$ctrl.tableData"></tabs>
```

For your question above , you need to bind `this` to a variable to `tabs`
 to get it work .

```
var tabs = this;
```

EDIT:

There is also a correction on your code . It should be ,

```
angular.module('widgets')
  .directive('tabs', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: 'info',
        transclude: true,
        bindToController: true,
        controllerAs: 'tabs',
        scope: {
            tabInfo: '=tabdata'
        },
        templateUrl: 'Template.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabs) {
            scope.$watch('tabs.tabInfo', function() {
                tabs.populateDataProvider();
            }, true);
        },
        controller: ['$filter', '$state', function($filter, $state) {
        }]
    };
});
```

Comment: where would i need to add var tabs = this ?  would it be in the link function?

Comment: @looneytunes Yes , inside the linking function

Comment: i added  this , still does not work, link: function(scope, element, attrs, tabs) {
                var tabs = this;
                scope.$watch('tabs.tabInfo', function() {
                    tabs.populateDataProvider();
                }, true);
            },

Comment: There is a correction , Plus , what I suggested in the comment would be a better option

Comment: It should in controller , not link function `controller: ['$filter', '$state', function($filter, $state) { var tabs = this
        }]`

Comment: and in link function  `scope.tabs.populateDataProvider();`